# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when authentication_string is correct

Tags: mysql, homebrew, access-denied

I have been stuck on this for days. I have a brew installation of mysql. What works for me to get into mysql..

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

$(brew --prefix mysql)/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

mysql -u root // or just mysql
```

So now I'm in. I have successfully changed the password for 'root'@'localhost' as per the results of this query..

```
mysql> select host, user, authentication_string from user;
+-----------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| host      | user             | authentication_string                                                  |
+-----------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| localhost | mysql.infoschema | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| localhost | mysql.session    | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| localhost | root             | pissword                                                               |
+-----------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However I still am unable to access mysql after exiting this process and starting the server normally..

```
mysqladmin -u root shutdown

launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

mysql -u root -ppissword

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Maybe I can check logs or something I don't know. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with the way you have changed the password. The correct syntax for that is

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass');
```

Don't forget to flush the privileges after that:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The thing is that in the `authentication_string` column you will have a hash of the password, not the raw password. That is what the `PASSWORD` function does.

Comment: I'm using mysql server 5.7.24 so that syntax should be correct [as per the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) but I get a syntax error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD('MyNewPass')'` I flushed privileges as well. Why would it matter how I changed the password?

Comment: In your post you are showing the result of the query. In the authentication_string column the value in the root row is 'pissword'. It looks like you changed the value directly on the column. The PASSWORD function created a hash of the password, and that value should be inside the user table. The password is never written in plain text.

Comment: I was unable to execute that or any similar statement without getting a syntax error. It could be an issue on my end with different versions of mysql installed and the path variables, etc. I removed mysql as completely as I could and reinstalled mysql. Now I can access the root without a password since none is set by default. Thank you